# Python csv compare header

Tags: python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python and have a question. I want to read multiple csv files, check for header and compare the header of the files.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames
import csv
root = Tk()
files= askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose files')

for i in range(len(files)):
   f = open('{}'.format(files[i])) 
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
   row = next(reader)
```

That is the code I already have. My problem is that I don't know how to read the header of the files and compare them.

I tried

```
    row[i] = next(reader)
```

but thats not working.

Comment: It's hard to help. Could you specify how/what you need to compare ? all headers have to be equals or you want to store the differences ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple Python example that reads a bunch of files and compares their header.

```
last_header = None
# Loop through the files
for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        # Read the header
        header = f.readline()
        # If this is the first file, then store the
        # header for later comparison
        if last_header == None:
            last_header = header
        # Check that the header match the last header
        elif header != last_header:
            print("Some information to user")
            quit()
        # Read the remaining lines
        lines = f.readlines()
```